# Switching primary network adapter on windows

Tags: python, powershell

I am writing a python script to select the network adapter that windows uses to reach the internet, for example switching from ethernet to Wi-Fi. I was wondering if there are specific powershell commands that can be used to accomplish this?

Comment: `Get-NetAdapter` can get you pointed in the right direction